# My Android app removed from Playstore for: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-advertising-id

I released my app on 30th July, Today I ran a Promotion Campain got a good amount of users but out of sudden got this email from Google Play Store.

[image]

It's a Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.

Now, See I didn't have any type of ads in my app. Didn't use Firebase Analytics. Firebase plugin I use is `cloud_firestore`. Only the In-app purchase. I used Flutter's official In-app purchase plugin and unlike what this email says not a single data from In-app-Purchase is saved to Firestore. The only info I save about a user is their Email.

I didn't have a background from Android and didn't know all nitty and gitty's about PlayStore. I searched on google and GitHub and nothing helpful comes out.

Can anyone help me with this? I am facing a huge loss since my Promotional Campaign have been started tho app is down. :(

Comment: first of all: stack overflow is about programming, not policy violations, so this question should be closed or moved to "proper stack". besides that: mail is saying that you haven't provide proper privacy policy - do you posted link in proper field in Play Console and also shown this link/button inside app?

Comment: See, what I found on Github is a  plugin in Flutter is saving Advertising ID, that's why I asked StackOverflow for help . Um...  I didn't provide a privacy policy. PlayStore Console didn't prompt me that's it's compulsory. Do you think it's the reason for the removal of my app?

Comment: It clearly states on the email that you need to provide a privacy policy both in the app and attached as a link when you publish the app on the play store. Have a look here: https://gdpr.eu/privacy-notice/ Although depending on the countries that can access you app you might be required to provide additional information in your privacy policy